# Using operator 'and' or 'or' to check if elements exists

Tags: xml, xpath, sonarqube, rules

I'm a newbie on XPath. I discovered XPath because I need to make rules to SonarQube to analize my PL/SQL code. I'm trying to check if the where clause contains some of these operators: `!=,  <>`. I managed check if contains `!=` or `<>` separately, but I need to add the 'OR' operator.

```
/*To catch <> operator*/
//WHERE_CLAUSE/EXPRESSION//*[self::NE_1]
```

and

```
/*To catch != operator*/
//WHERE_CLAUSE/EXPRESSION//*[self::NE_2]
```

What way to union the two expressions using 'OR'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//WHERE_CLAUSE/EXPRESSION//*[self::NE_1 or self::NE_2]
```

will select all `NE_1` and `NE_2` descendants of `//WHERE_CLAUSE/EXPRESSION`.